# Replace nan values with row max in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following dataframe (df):

```
PARTY_ID O1 O2 O3 O4
P1 20 NA NA NA
P2 3 18 NA NA
```

I need to replace NA values with the maximum value of each row. My desired output is:

```
PARTY_ID O1 O2 O3 O4
P1 20 20 20 20
P2 3 18 18 18
```

I need to do this quickly because my data has 600K rows. 
Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have reproducible data set, but maybe this works:

```
t(apply(df_mat, 1, function(x) {ifelse(is.na(x), max(x, na.rm = TRUE), x)}))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it doesn't replace the NA values :c

Comment: I have forgot na.rm=TRUE. Can you try now?

Answer (score 2):

There can be multiple options using `tidyverse` & `reshape2` packages.

**Option#1:** You can covert data in long format and work on it. Finally convert it back to wide format using `dcast`.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(reshape2)

df %>% gather(Key, Value, -PARTY_ID) %>%
  group_by(PARTY_ID) %>%
  mutate(Value = ifelse(is.na(Value), max(Value, na.rm = TRUE), Value)) %>%
  dcast(PARTY_ID~Key, value.var = "Value")

#   PARTY_ID O1 O2 O3 O4
# 1       P1 20 20 20 20
# 2       P2  3 18 18 18
```

**Option#2:** OP has mentioned as she got huge rows (`600K`) in data.frame. Hence, another option is to work on data in wide format itself. `dplyr::mutate_at` will be of great help in this case. I would have preferred this option.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(RowMax = apply(select(.,starts_with("O")), 1, FUN=max, na.rm=TRUE)) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("O")), funs(ifelse(is.na(.), RowMax,.))) %>%
  select(-RowMax)

#   PARTY_ID O1 O2 O3 O4
# 1       P1 20 20 20 20
# 2       P2  3 18 18 18
```

**Data:**

```
df <- read.table(text = 
"PARTY_ID O1 O2 O3 O4
P1 20 NA NA NA
P2 3 18 NA NA",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution from `zoo` `na.locf`

```
data.frame(t(na.locf(t(A))))

  PARTY_ID O1 O2 O3 O4
1       P1 20 20 20 20
2       P2  3 18 18 18
```

Comment: Sorry, but it didn't work. It is A the name of my dataframe? In that case, my output is:  `X167302   X167303   X167304`

Answer (score 1):

This should be very fast as it is a single assignment rather than row-by-row:

```
idxna <- which(is.na(df[-1]), arr.ind=TRUE)
df[-1][idxna] <- do.call(pmax, c(df[-1], na.rm=TRUE))[idxna[,"row"]]
df

#  PARTY_ID O1 O2 O3 O4
#1       P1 20 20 20 20
#2       P2  3 18 18 18
```

Using @MKR's data.